# What is the suitable word to use after the word fall or drop to mean it dropped a lot?

Tags: synonyms

In particular i have an index in mind. I think the word heavily is okay, but is there a better word? Or even better is there a word to mean dropped heavily?

Comment: I think this is Primarily Opinion-Based, since there are lots of ways to express what OP wants to say. But probably the most common is a ***steep fall***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes! Thank you. I got to start using this forum to improve my English!

Comment: To my mind, ELU isn't really the right place for questions like this (I posted my comment after voting to close, and you can see from Susan's answer that there are many valid alternatives). If you're looking to improve your English, you might consider asking your next question on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the stock market, a *sharp* drop is pretty bad. A *plunge* in stock price is also serious. A stock price can **plummet**, *bottom out*, or *crash*, although the latter is used more of a collective drop.

Answer (score 3):

[Precipitously](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/precipitously) may be the word you're looking for:

> very steeply: "The ground beyond the road fell away precipitously."  "a precipitously plunging neckline" "The fortress town is perched precipitously on a gorge."
>
> suddenly or quickly: "They've got to act precipitously to make the deals." "The company has seen its profits fall precipitously over the past few years."
>
> hastily or rashly: "With fiery Mars in Leo, you could act precipitously."

Answer (score 2):

How about *repeatedly*? As for heavily, the word *thud* is hard to beat.

> "The repeated thud of the sledgehammer woke me with a start."

Thudding, thudded, [thuddingly](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/thud?db=dictionary), and thuds are cognates.

Hey, "thud" can be used metaphorically, as in "The sudden thud of Apple stock prices took everyone by surprise."

Comment: I meant fall of an index like SP500 or apple stock price?

Comment: Hey, "thud" can be used metaphorically, as in "The sudden thud of Apple stock prices took everyone by surprise."

Comment: ah i see. This is great english, but i am looking for a more boring word, because this is a research article i am proofreading. I thinks dropped heavily is a bit poor but thud would be too dramatic! But +1, i learnt something today...

Comment: @Lost1: With all due respect to rhetorician, ***thud*** would be an unlikely word in the context of stock prices, since the metaphoric reference there is to ***hitting the 'floor'***. That would tend to imply, for example, the value of Apple shares falling to ***zero*** (and in such an astonishing scenario even words like ***thud*** would seem inadequate).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Apple was used simply for illustrative purposes. Perhaps the following would be better (again, for illustrative purposes and not because there is no such traded company): "The sudden thud of Bernie Madoff Industries was heard around the world."

Comment: @rhetorician: Yes, I'm not saying such metaphoric usages would *never* occur. But ELU isn't a "creative writing" forum, and it seems highly likely OP isn't a native speaker anyway, so it seems to me he's best served by taking note of the more "standard" usages as set down by Susan (which are so common many people wouldn't even consciously recognize that they're all figurative).